# I'm having some issues to see some flags dynamically added on the highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having an issue when I add flags dynamically to a Highcharts chart. The thing is that when I do so, the flags are not drawn on the chart until I do something that makes the chart refresh (for example, drag the mouse over some button with a tooltip).

I've noticed that this has something to do with the fact that I add the flags inside a point's click event.

```
point: {
   events: {
      'click': function() {}
   }
}
```

I assume this is the case since when I add flags to the chart in other parts of the code they appear instantly.

What could be the reason of this behavior?

Comment: It would be helpful to see exactly what code you use to add a flag.

Comment: Please replicate your example as live demo, (jsfiddle.net, please)

Comment: Thank you guys for your time. I fixed it! I was using highcharts-ng complement, because i'm working with Angular, and the problem was that i was missing a $scope.$apply() sentence at the end of my function that adds the flags to the chart.